# kangamodeling and displaying graphs fails

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

`Have you any idea why the following code snip I use doesn't produce the expected graph on the browser ?

I have added script tag pointing to latest jquery and kangamodeling's js scripts already.

http://jsfiddle.net/y94Qy/

Thank you for any instructions.

Comment: Moderator: please add a `kangamodeling` tag to this question, I could not create it myself.

Answer (score 0):

from what I've found so far is that it doesn't seem to work in IE. At least for me using IE9 - simulating IE7 and IE8.

However, for Jsfiddle, the script needs to looks like:http://jsfiddle.net/anAgent/6BcQR/

Just put the include script in the HTML box.